# Pigeonhole coloring bound

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle, coloring, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, jensen-inequality

[image]

I am stuck on this problem from a combinatorics book. I tried applying the pigeonhole principle to show that there are at least n/r numbers with the same color, and applied the formula for (x choose 2) to compute the number of pairs, but didn't get to the inequality we need to prove.

I also tried considering how many pairs are in each of the r pigeonholes, and considering that (x choose 2) is convex, I tried to apply Jensen's Inequality to simplify, but also did not reach the desired inequality. I would greatly appreciate any explanations with steps.

Comment: It's likely a typo. The RHS should be $ r \times { \frac{ n}{r} \choose 2 } = \frac{n(n-1) } { r } $. This follows from your second paragraph.